# Кто может помочь, что за ошибка?

Tags: java

Кто может помоч, что за ошибка?

> AxisFault
>    faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
>    faultSubcode: 
>    faultString: (403)
>    faultActor: 
>    faultNode: 
>    faultDetail: 
>       {}:return code:  403
>   <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status [403] – [Forbidden]</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status [403] – [Forbidden]</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Description</b> The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.15</h3></body></html>
>       {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HttpErrorCode:403
>
> (403)

---

Серваки говорят проблема с авторизации с headerom. Как могу проверить авторизации

Comment: Тяжело утверждать с точностью по такой постановке вопроса, но похоже, что у клиента нет прав на выполнение запроса, который он отправил серверу.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Как я могу проверить авторизации?